# Dojox chart not working. It throws 404 error with dojox.js

Tags: dojo, dojox.charting

We have been using Custom Dojo build and it is working fine for all the modules of Dijit and some of Dojox modules.

However when we try to do require (["dojox/charting/Chart"}) or some other modules of Dojox it gives following javascript error. I looked at the modules closely and I found that each such modules use "." to load the dependencies from relative paths.

> GET /somepath/js/dojox.js 404 (Not Found)

I don't understand why dojo is looking for dojox.js which is not part of even Dojo source.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Hmm, do any of the modules by chance have `define(["dojox", ....` in them? I don't think that works anymore.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. But I realized that in earlier Dojo build I didn't select dojox package. So in Dojo.js configuration was missing in package like ["dojox", "../dojox"]. I just put that and it is working fine for me now.